# What format is used in the LXC config file to specify control group settings?

Tags: performance, lxc

I want to limit the CPU shares of available to two LXC containers running.

It appears that this is done by adding the control group definitions into the LXC config file.

But what's the format? The Ubuntu server docs stop short of explaining how to do this.

Specifically I'd like to do this:

- Container A is guaranteed 80% cpu as needed, Container B 20%
- Basically the same block I/O access guarantees as we have for CPU above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Between these two pages of documentation I have what I need:

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man5/lxc.conf.5.html

https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Resource_Management_Guide/sec-cpu.html